# Display html blank code in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I display this code `&#8203;`  for the user to copy  without adding spaces

I tried to add code tags

```
<code>&#8203;</code>
```

but didn't work  how can I do it ?

Comment: `<code>&amp;#8203;</code>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try

```
<code>&amp;#8203;</code>
```

Comment: Thank you that was easy  I was look for &#  alternatives but I couldn't find them.